# Alter Table With Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named ITEM with fields ID, TYPE, DES, SIZE now i want to add a foreign key from another table AISLE which has field of AISLE_ID, X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT. Now i want the AISLE_ID to be the foreign key in the ITEM table. I used this statement but says the AISLE_ID is not recognized. This is the statement i used

```
ALTER table ITEM 
ADD FOREIGN KEY AISLE_ID(AISLE_ID)
REFERENCES AISLE(AISLE_ID)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Any Help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the `AISLE_ID` columns exist in both tables?!

Comment: no it does not!!it is only in the AISLE table. But i tried adding the AISLE_ID but it gave me another exception!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ALTER` statement to be like below, since there is only matching column in `ITEM` per `AISLE_ID` definition type in `AISLE`; consider making the `ID` column in `ITEM` table to be the foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE ITEM ADD CONSTRAINT fk_AISLE_ID 
FOREIGN KEY (ID) references AISLE(AISLE_ID)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

You can as well `ALTER` the `ITEM` table and add a column named `AISLE_ID` and then create a foreign key on it like

```
ALTER TABLE ITEM ADD  AISLE_ID INT NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE ITEM ADD CONSTRAINT fk_AISLE_ID 
FOREIGN KEY (AISLE_ID) references AISLE(AISLE_ID)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: doesn't work!!  #1072 - Key column 'AISLE_ID' doesn't exist in table

Comment: that's great, then how can you add a constraint on that. Consider providing all relevant info in your post. Post the table structure for table `ITEM`

Comment: MY item table consists this structure,CREATE TABLE ITEM (
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    TYPE VARCHAR (32) NOT NULL, 
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
    SIZE FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    SIZE_TYPE VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
    MANUFACTURE VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL, 
    SECTION VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL, 
    PRICE FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    LEVEL INT(1) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),

Comment: The above is the item table now the aisal table is:
create table aisle( AISLE_ID INT NOT NULL 
                    X INT NOT NULL
                    Y INT NOT NULL
                    HEIGHT INT NOT NULL
                    WEIGHT INT NOT NULL
                    PRIMARY KEY (AISAL_ID). NOw i want the AISAL_ID TO be the foreign key in the item table using alter. And thank you so much for your reply

Comment: @sanjuwere, Check edited answer again. Also, consider editing your post and include this table structure from comment.

Comment: there is error saying this #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`show_me_where`.&lt;result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-15f3_1af213b'&gt;, CONSTRAINT `fk_AISLE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`AISLE_ID`) REFERENCES `AISLE` (`AISLE_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: @sanjuwere, pls don't mix up multiple question in a single post. From your comment it's clear that, foreign key creation is successful. You are getting error cause, you are trying to insert a row in child table without inserting the same key value in parent table. Insert in parent table first.

Comment: actually the second syntax did not create the foreign key. The firt syntax created a field but the second syntax was not useful.